# Optimum approach in database design

Tags: mysql, optimization, database-design

I have a table POSTS in mysql database its columns are

```
Column       DataType
POSTID       Int(11) PK
Userid       Int(11) FK
Content      varchar(100)
Type         TINYINT

Type field can take values image, text, video, link, question, repost.
```

My question is this design optimum if this tables is expected to have too many entries like billions of entries. What factors should I take into account? Should I divide this table into multiple tables like Images, Texts, Videos, Links, Question, Repost or should I go for one table solution?

Comment: Think about *Partitioning*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One table solution is the way you should go for, as it will be **much** easier to query and index. Anyway, if your product is new, this table will not have that many entries before a long time, and preoptimization is the best way to lose time during development.

I advise you to keep it like you did, and think about solutions that already exist when you will have those concerns in production (maybe a SQL engine is not the best for that kind of data?).

Also, i would change the `type` column type from `TINYINT` to `ENUM`.

Comment: You are right about changing TINYINT to ENUM, but again, the product is not new its just improvement, we have like million records in almost about 100 places a total of it becomes 0.1 billion then for each record we'll be processing multiple type of reports (monthly) so if i am keeping that monthly data in a table can i divide that report table again i want answer that address design optimization